# What is `bash -x`

Tags: bash, debugging

A colleague recently introduced me to `bash -x` for debugging my bash scripts without taking the `echo $foo` route.

```
$ bash -x hello-world.sh 
+ echo 'Hello World'
Hello World
```

Internally -- how does bash accomplish this?  I checked `man bash` and it (didn't seem to?) mention the `-x` flag when invoking the interpreter.   I'm mainly looking for an overview of what will and won't be debugged in the `-x` enviornment, or any other gotchas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`-x` is the same as setting `xtrace` with the `-o` option to bash.  From my copy of the bash manpage:

> After  expanding  each *simple command*, **for** command, **case** command, **select** command, or arithmetic **for** command, display  the expanded value of **PS4**, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or associated word list.

I don't think there are many "gotchas" with this: it prints each command it executes.  I suppose if you're parsing the `stderr` output from the shell script, this can mess that up, because the commands are printed to `stderr` (aka file descriptor 2), but that seems like an extreme case.

(You can also conditionally enable this inside scripts or in interactive shell sessions with `set -x` to turn it on and `set +x` to turn it off again.)

Comment: Oof. Thank you. `set help` just says `-x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.`. I couldn't find anything on how to _unset_ that in the current shell.

Comment: @sherrellbc: `set help` sets the positional parameters to the word `help` and doesn't output anything. `help set` gives one line or so for each option, including the one you show for `-x` in my (older) version, and at the end of that list says `Using + rather than - causes these flags to be turned off.`